# How to add opacity to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add opacity to a div.

Here is my Jquery:

```
$('.redDiv').fadeIn(0, 0.5);
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="redDiv" style="background:red;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>
<div class="divBlue;" style="background:blue;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>
<div class="divBlack;" style="background:black;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>
```

Comment: Jquery how to add opacity to a div?

Comment: @Rails: You said _that_ much already. Delan is asking you to ask a _real_, well-formed, detailed question, not just to repeat the question title which we can already plainly see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this:

```
$('.redDiv').css("opacity", "0.5"); //Immediately sets opacity
$('.redDiv').fadeTo(0, 0.5);        //Animates the opacity to 50% over the course of 0 milliseconds.  Increase the 0 if you want to animate it.
$('.redDiv').fadeIn();              //Animates the opacity from 0 to 100%
```

If an element has `display:none` fadeTo and fadeIn will both make the element visible before fading it

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to help:

```
$("div").css("opacity", ".7");
```

The [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method that you're calling doesn't *just* apply opacity to an element, but does so from a starting point (transparent) to an endpoint (opaque), essentially animating the element with the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Use fadeTo method

```
$('.redDiv').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
$('.redDiv').css("opacity", "0.5");
```